# Segment Base for moffs16/32

Tags: assembly, x86, instructions, opcode

I was going through the different MOV instructions and had a doubt regarding one of them. The **MOV moffs16/32, AX** instruction. According to the Intel manual: "*The moffs8, moffs16, moffs32 and moffs64operands specify a simple offset relative to the segment base, where 8, 16, 32 and 64 refer to the size of the data.*" The opcode for the instruction is A3 and what I would like to know is which segment register is the offset relative to? Is it CS, DS or ES?

Answer (score 3):

As per section *3.7.4 Specifying a Segment Selector* in the basic architecture manual:

> The segment selector can be specified either implicitly or explicitly. [...]
>   The processor automatically chooses a segment according to
>   the rules given in Table 3-5.
>
> `SS` Any memory reference which uses the ESP or EBP register as a base
>   register.
>
> `DS` All data references, except when relative to stack or
>   string destination.

The instruction in the question only uses a single constant offset so no effective address with registers. As such, it's `DS` unless overridden by a prefix.